# How do I close this hole in the HVAC vent?

Tags: hvac, furnace, venting

What's the best way to close up this hole in the venting leaving the hvac?

Would foil tape be sufficient? Right now it bleeds out hot air into the basement in the winter, and cold air in the summer.

[image: Furnace Vent Hole]

<sub>Click for full size image</sub>

Comment: What hole? I don't see an open hole.

Comment: In between those two pipes is open.  It should be noted this part is the main vent out from the furnace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

If you're talking about the seam (circled in red). Then yes, foil tape is appropriate.

However, if you're talking about sealing around the pipe (circled in orange). You'll want to use [Duct Seal](http://www.idealindustries.com/prodDetail.do?prodId=duct-seal&div=5&l1=accessories), or an equivalent product.

[image]

Comment: I was talking about the orange circle.  Hadn't really noticed the red one, but I should definitely use foil tape on that.  Thanks!

Comment: In the auto industry, we call that duct seal dum-dum. Very tacky body sealer that will attach to any surface, is formable to fill any void and retains its shape under a broad temperature range. One of its uses is to fill holes around cables and hoses to seal up any gaps the rubber grommets don't fill.

Comment: @FiascoLabs wasn't sure how wide spread the nickname dum-dum was. First heard it at a garage I apprenticed at, I was never sure that anyone else would understand what I was talking about if I used that term elsewhere!

Answer (score -3):

Foil tape will work just fine.  This is how I've got mine closed off.

Comment: -1 this appears to be a "me too" answer rather than voting on another answer.